# Trying to investigate page load performance bug: What is "Scripting" and "Idle"?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, performance, performance-testing

I have a site built on HTML/CSS/JS/PHP/MySQL and I'm trying to determine what is consuming the bulk of the operations involved in loading my pages. Google Chrome's timeline shows

[image]

and I'm wondering what is "Scripting" and "Idle"? With that said, what is "Painting"?

Comment: My impression is that `Scripting` is time spent executing JavaScript, which could cause the page to load differently; `Rendering` is figuring out how to put things on screen (calculating sizes of divs, etc), while `Painting` is probably time spent actually putting it onscreen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scripting is defined by the scripting events in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/performance-reference#scripting-events

Painting events are described as well.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/performance-reference#painting-events

Idle seems to be time that is not spent handling *any* events.

Comment: So the Idle could be my server-side ish that I'm afraid is bogging down the performance?

Comment: @PeterThiel Not sure tbh. But you could easily test for it. Make an AJAX request to a PHP script that sleeps for 10 seconds before responding and see if that counts as idle time or not.